# How to enable Eclipse to autobuild/autosave changes before run (CDT)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, autosave, auto-build

I'm trying to conveniently have the updated code in effect when I click the run button in Eclipse.  At present it will run the last build and I have to manually click build before clicking run to see the changes.

Can someone advise me on how to configure Eclipse to autobuild the current project (if changes has been made) before running the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple settings for auto building.  The one you could be missing is the setting under ***Launching***.

[image]

Two other settings are here:

[image]

And the last setting is the one you likely already know about:

[image]

Comment: when trying to create a new c++ hello world project, it does not build automatically. Is it compulsory to build each project atleast once manually, it doesn't happen even by applying all the above settings?

Comment: I would create a new question and add the output you receive when run try to run/launch the program after an edit.

Comment: I have already created a question concerning this, still no one has answered ! Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703149/eclipse-cdt-hello-world-project-doesnt-build-automatically

Answer (score 5):

If you want to automatically build your project on save (or before run, if needed), then from tool-bar menu go to

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Select Behaviour Tab on the right panel, -> tick the "Build on resource save(Auto build)"  , finally hit OK

That is it...