# Eclipse CDT - Hello World Project doesn't build automatically

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I am new to eclipse. I tried creating new C++ project through 
`File-> New -> C++ Project -> Hello World C++ Project`. When I try to launch it, it gives me error:

`Launch Failed, Binary not found`.

However, when I right click on the project, choose the `Build Project` option, and then press the launch button, the hello world program executes successfully.

I have tried enabling the build automatically options at each place specified by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959595/how-to-enable-eclipse-to-autobuild-autosave-changes-before-run-cdt) . Still it doesn't work for me unless I manually build it.

Is it mandatory to build it manually at first before it can be launched? I don't have any such problem when using eclipse for java projects.

I am using Eclipse Luna version 4.4.

Comment: Did you research on Eclipse's site if there's a bug reported for this behavior?

Comment: yes, but nowhere I could find such a bug reported. Even I am not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: Is auto build enabled?

Comment: i tried whatever I could, followed this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959595/how-to-enable-eclipse-to-autobuild-autosave-changes-before-run-cdt

Comment: @Basilevs auto-build, where should I enable?

Comment: when I create a C project in eclipse, I have to build it 'manually' the first time.  Thereafter, when I edit anything and click run/run it rebuilds itself and runs.