# C++ Ecipse: Save Before Running a Program

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, autosave

I try to learn C++ and because I'm already familiar with Eclipse (PHP, JavaScript, HTML (CSS), Java) I downloaded Eclipse for C / C++ Developers.

The others versions of Eclipse I used over the past years always had an easy way to save automatically before doing certain things. And Eclipse for C / C++ Developers seamed to have the same thing and it might be that it actually worked yesterday (but then again, I was really tired).

Everything I found regarding this is either what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959595/how-to-enable-eclipse-to-autobuild-autosave-changes-before-run-cdt) or a subset of what's described there. However, this doesn't work for me. (I of course tried restarting Eclipse.)

I'm running the newest version (which I downloaded yesterday from the official website) of Eclipse for C / C++ Developers in the 64 bit version for Linux on an Ubuntu machine. I checked for updates via the internal tool and Eclipse is up to date.

This is what "About Eclipse" says:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200
```

Comment: Is there "Save required dirty editors before launching" set to something different than "Never" in the Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching ?

Comment: Is was set to "Prompt" and I now set it to "Always". It works. Thank you! :) Want to write this as an answer?

Comment: There is a comprehensive answer in the link you referred. It is only missing one red arrow :)

Comment: Yes. I assumed you'd only have to change the marked values.